# Stemming text in R

Tags: r, text-mining

I am stemming my text data in R. I am using a solution proposed by Yanchang Zhao for the latest version of tm package but found this very slow. I am looking for an alternative way.

```
myCorpusCopy <- myCorpus

stemCompletion2 <- function(x, dictionary) {
x <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), " "))
x <- x[x != ""]
x <- stemCompletion(x, dictionary=dictionary)
x <- paste(x, sep="", collapse=" ") 
PlainTextDocument(stripWhitespace(x)) }


 myCorpus <- lapply(myCorpus, stemCompletion2, dictionary=myCorpusCopy)

 myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(myCorpus))
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply **stemming** during preprocessing to reduce words to their basic form.

Porter stemmer is okay for English, and rather fast.

Comment: I edited my question.